# Delete all images added to canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, wpf-controls

Is there a possible way to remove (delete) all images (children) added to a `Canvas` in C# (in WFP)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do you mean you just want to remove all the child elements?

```
canvas.Children.Clear();
```

looks like it should do the job.

EDIT: If you *only* want to remove the `Image` elements, you can use:

```
var images = canvas.Children.OfType<Image>().ToList();
foreach (var image in images)
{
    canvas.Children.Remove(image);
}
```

This assumes all the images are *direct* child elements though - if you want to remove `Image` elements under other elements, it becomes trickier.

Answer (score 6):

Since the children collection of a Canvas is a UIElementCollection and there are plenty of other controls that use this type of collection, we could add remove method to all of them with an extension method.

```
public static class CanvasExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all instances of a type of object from the children collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object you want to remove.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="targetCollection">A reference to the canvas you want items removed from.</param>
    public static void Remove<T>(this UIElementCollection targetCollection)
    {
        // This will loop to the end of the children collection.
        int index = 0;

        // Loop over every element in the children collection.
        while (index < targetCollection.Count)
        {
            // Remove the item if it's of type T
            if (targetCollection[index] is T)
                targetCollection.RemoveAt(index);
            else
                index++;
        }
    }
}
```

When this class is present you can simply remove all images (or any other type of object) with the line.

```
testCanvas.Children.Remove<Image>();
```